# (iOS)Unable to read vide frames with AVURLAsset and AVAsset reader from RAM and not a file

Tags: ios, objective-c, mp4, nsurl, avasset

I have an app with a custom resource format file.
Inside that file there are bytes dedicated to store an mp4 file as is.
I am trying to play this mp4 file, but I am unable to, because:
1) I cannot create an AVURLAsset from a segment inside a file.\
2) I am unable to play an AVURLAsset with the data scheme, or any other way that will allow me to play the asset from a cpu allocated memory.

What I currently do is just save the mp4 into it's own file on the drive, then play the mp4 from the temporary file I just created.
This work, but it might be problematic if the app using this file will use the file system as well, or all sort of unknown future problems doing it this way.

Here is the code that works with saving the file:

```
@autoreleasepool {
            NSString *filePath = documentsPathForFileName(@"video.mp4");
            [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
            NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
            frameCounter = 0;
            asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:url];
            if(asset == nil) {
              NSLog(@"Cannot create AVURLAsset");
            } else {

              NSLog(@"Asset: %@", asset);
            }

            if([asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].count == 0) {
              NSLog(@"No Video Track");
            } else if([asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio].count == 0) {
              NSLog(@"No Audio Track");
            }
        }
```

In this case I am getting one video track and can read the frames with an AVAssetReader.

Here is one of my attempts to use the data scheme with base64, it opens the AVAssetURL but doesn't find any track inside of it.

```
        NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        @autoreleasepool {
            NSString* dataFormatString = @"data:video/mp4;base64,%@";

            NSString* dataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:dataFormatString, strData];
            NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:dataString];
            frameCounter = 0;
            asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:url];
            if(asset == nil) {
              NSLog(@"Cannot create AVURLAsset");
            } else {

              NSLog(@"Asset: %@", asset);
            }

            if([asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].count == 0) {
              NSLog(@"No Video Track");
            } else if([asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio].count == 0) {
              NSLog(@"No Audio Track");
            }
        }
```

I am able to create the AVAssetURL but it doesn't file any tracks inside.
It doesn't matter if I try to use fileURLWithPath instead of URLWithString

I tried using AVAssetResourceDelegateLoader, but I think it would require for me to use ffmpeg inside, which would defeat the purpose.

Comment: There is an error in the second code, even if I do: NSString * strData = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0] It doesn't work.

Comment: I have found a solution to my own problem, but it has memory leaks. You can see it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61617762/other-processes-untraceable-memory-leaks-when-using-avassetresourceloaderdeleg